# Cannot see Texture and Shader option in Compositor

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am new to blender. I saw in the tutorials to add shader and texture but don't seem to find any such thing after pressing shift + a.

[image]

Comment: Shift + A gives you the list of **groupped** nodes. Hover the mouse cursor and select the node you want.

Answer (score 1):

The texture and shader options are only available in the shader node editor, whereas you are in the compositing editor:

[image] [image]